# What to ignore in Git with Cowboy / erlang.mk project?

Tags: git, erlang, gnu-make, gitignore, cowboy

While learning Erlang I'm following [Cowboy's HTTP framework documentation to setup a simple server](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/getting_started/). I understand that the project structure is driven by `erlang.mk`. Now having something working I want to commit the code to Git repository. What are the recommended entries for `.gitignore` file? I did a little googling, but couldn't find any guides.

My guesses and considerations are:

```
## From GitHub template:
.eunit
deps
*.o
*.beam
*.plt
erl_crash.dump
ebin/*.beam
rel/example_project   # Is this a template?
                      # Shouldn't I ignore entire rel directory?
.concrete/DEV_MODE
.rebar

## erlang.mk specific?
_rel                  # Not sure what this is, but looks generated.
*.d                   # These are generated by Make, right?
.erlang.mk            # It is referred to as temp directory in erlang.mk file.
```

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you already found [this .gitignore on github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Erlang.gitignore).

Note that you do not want to exclude `rel`, as the configuration files there will be part of your release. As a rule of thumb, ignore hidden files, directories with `_` prepended, `deps`, `ebin`. So, your ignore file looks good, except the entry on `rel`. I would also include `logs`, as soon as you start writing tests with [common_test](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/introduction.html).

Additionally, as you are not using [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar), you can delete `.rebar` as well.

Comment: Just to be sure: entire `ebin` directory should be ignored? Currently I have some `.beam` files and `cowboy_playground.app` file there, which seems to be regenerated whenever I build. The GitHub template only ignores `ebin/*.beam`.

Comment: So, this is what I finally have there: https://github.com/lzrski/cowboy-playground/blob/master/.gitignore Hope it will help others :)

Comment: Regarding `ebin/`: If you place files there yourself, you should only exclude `ebin/*beam`. Note however that `erlang.mk` [takes care](https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk/blob/master/doc/src/guide/app.asciidoc#application-resource-file) of generating `ebin/*.app` files for you; either from the Makefile, or from a `src/*.app.src` file. I use the second approach if I need a custom `.app` file, as that neatly separates code from compiled entities.